# datasource.rowIdentifier is undefined error in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am accessing data from database and I wanted to display it in ListView.
I am performing this operation in following way.

```
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

const LoadingPage=()=>(
   <View style={{backgroundColor:"blue"}}>
     <Image style={{width:150, height:100,bottom:60}} source={require('./drawable/drawable/asap.png')}/>

  </View>
)
const Row = (props) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <Text style={styles.text}>
      {`${props.paymentType.name} ${props.amount} ${props.date} ${props.description}`}
  </Text>
  </View>
);

async fetchData(){
    var DEMO_TOKEN = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);

    fetch(" http://asaptest-sas71.rhcloud.com/api/approvals", {
         method: 'get',
         dataType: 'json',
         headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': DEMO_TOKEN
         },
        }).then((response) => 
         {
           return response.json() // << This is the problem
         }).then(function(data) { 
            console.log(data);
            const tempNames = [];    

            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
              tempNames.push(data[i]);
            }
            this.setState({ approvals: tempNames,dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.approvals)});
            alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.approvals,null,4))



          }.bind(this)).catch(function(err) {
            //alert("Error is"+err)

           console.log(err);
         })
        .done();

}
componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
   setTimeout(this.setTimePassed()
          , 2000) ;
}
setTimePassed() {
 this.setState({timePassed: true});
}
render(){
  if (!this.state.timePassed){
  return <LoadingPage/>
  }
  else{
    return (

      <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}  
     />)
  }
 }
```

But it is giving error that undefined is not an object(evaluating  'dataSource.rowidentifiers')
Please help me solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please can you refactor to using `FlatList` instead. It's so much easier to use and has improvements over the `ListView`. And my bet is your error would disappear when you change to using a FlatList.

Reason why: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html

Docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html

An article on migrating from ListView to FlatList: https://hackernoon.com/react-native-new-flatlist-component-30db558c7a5b

Cheers